# Some playlists are missing from iTunes Match

Tags: music, itunes-match, playlist

I've just subscribed for iTunes Match and it did quite a good job of matching stuff except that three of my playlists are missing from it. That three missing playlists only show up on my iMac which is my source Mac for my entertainment.

I tried duplicating and renaming those three missing playlists with no luck.

Comment: Has iTunes Match completely uploaded everything? Are the three playlists Smart Playlists?

Comment: iTunes Match is complete and those three are not smart playlists.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the iCloud Download and iCloud Status columns in iTunes?  (In View > Show View Options on a Mac.)  I've had this problem when a particular item within a playlist couldn't be uploaded to iTunes Match.

Comment: @Ashley It's all matched or purchased. What was it like in your situation?

Comment: I think for me, some hadn't been uploaded yet, or perhaps the playlist contained a voice memo (which it wouldn't upload): I can't remember exactly, sorry about that.  I've also had to do Store > Turn Off iTunes Match, then turn it on again more than once... perhaps your next step.

Comment: @Ashley Turning iTunes Match off and on again actually worked. Thanks a lot :) Also would you please consider writing your solution comment as an answer instead so that other people having this problem in the future will find the solution easier

Comment: Excellent!  I've written that as an answer now we've figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Ashley's solution solved it for a while the problem happened again therefore I tried her solution again. But it didn't stop. It happened again.

Today, it came to my mind out of nowhere that some playlist not syncing while some others were successfully syncing might be due to the ineligible songs in those not syncing playlists. And that seems to be the case.

I removed all of the ineligible songs from those playlists and they instantly showed up on my other devices.

In order to show the ineligible songs in your iTunes, you have to click the header of the songs view in your library and select iCloud status. Selecting this will add an additional column about each of your songs' iTunes Match status.

This seems like a bug in iTunes Match since it can sync playlists with ineligible songs at first but not afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem: smart playlist hidden on the iPhone, but fixed playlist (not the smart ones) correctly synchronized.

In my smart playlist, i put a condition like "playlist not 'xxx'".  While working on my pc, where the xxx playlist contains already downloaded files, it did not work on the iPhone, because the mobile has no clue how to handle the request.

I changed the playlist, and deleted the dependancy between other playlist, and... tadam... I saw the smart playlist happear on the iPhone.

I hope it will help.

Hans

Comment: Yup - removing the "Playlist is..." requirement fixed it. That sux.

Answer (score 3):

1. Turn on the *iCloud Download* and *iCloud Status* columns in iTunes, using View > Show View Options (on a Mac).  Look for items with problems: for example, voice memos, which can't be uploaded to iTunes Match.
2. If step 1 doesn't reveal any problems, **try turning off iTunes Match** (via Store > Turn Off iTunes Match), then turn it on again.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find an answer to this for a week (since Music Match got a mind of its own).  Quite by accident, I went to the "More" section of the Music app on my iPhone 5 (with iOS7).  The last choice is "Shared".  There I found a choice between my iPhone and my Library (on my Mac).  I switched from my iPhone to my Library and -- voila -- my playlists showed up on my iPhone.  There are still 34 songs missing on my iPhone.  But, I think they are from 6 albums that also don't show up.  I am not in the mood to do a complete reconciliation.  I will leave well enough alone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, It turned out to be the songs that I was missing were mis-categorized as audiobooks and they were in my audiobook section in the Books tab.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered what I THINK happened to my missing playlists. What was happening was that 2 of my playlists weren't syncing, and even if I made a new copy of them (I was trying anything at this point) they still wouldn't sync. So I tried turning off/on iTunes Match again. It then authorized my computer again. However, when it came back on, while it was syncing information to the cloud I discovered that there were a few songs on each playlist that were "unchecked" (I have no idea why or how they got that way) so I checked them again and BAM my playlists showed up on my iOS device within 60 seconds. So I'm not sure if it was the turning off/on of the iTunes Match that did it, or if it was the simple checked/unchecked issue. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the songs under "albums" on my iPhone and create a playlist. Not really a great solution but a work around.